# Counting tuples of subsets for which every subtuple of a given size has union equal to the entire set

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I have a question which is a refined version of the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700912/counting-tuples-of-subsets-whose-union-is-the-set). Let $A = \{1,\ldots,n\}$, $S_r = \{a \subset A: |a| = r\}$ for $0 < r \leq n$, $S_r^m = \{(a_1,\ldots,a_m) : a_i \in S_r \}$ for $m>0$, and consider, for $0 < d \leq m$, the set $$ U^n_{r,m,d} = \{ T \in S_r^m : \text{ the union of any $d$ components of $T$ equals $A$}\} \subset S_r^m $$

Note that $U^n_{r,m,1} \subset U^n_{r,m,2} \subset \cdots \subset U^n_{r,m,m} \subset S_r^m$.

**I'm interested in computing $\tau(n,r,m,d) \triangleq |U^n_{r,m,d}|$.**

My first guess is to use an inclusion-exclusion argument. I'll run through it to illustrate where it gets stuck (as far as I can tell). We try to calculate the cardinality of the complement of $U^n_{r,m,d}$, say $S_r^m = U^n_{r,m,d} \sqcup V^n_{r,m,d}$. For $\ell \in A$ let $ K_{\ell} = \{ (a_1,\ldots,a_m) \in S_r^m : \exists i_1,\ldots,i_d \text{ with }  
 \ell \notin \cup_j a_{i_j} \}$, wherefore $$ V^n_{r,m,d} = \bigcup_{\ell \in A} K_\ell $$ To proceed we are required to be able to express the cardinality of $\bigcap_{j \in J} K_j$, for $J \subset A$. **I don't know how to do this.** It seems tricky to count: if $(a_1,\ldots,a_m) \in K_1 \cap K_2$, we know that for some $i_1,\ldots,i_d$, $1 \notin \cup_j a_{i_j}$, and for some $k_1,\ldots,k_d$, $2 \notin \cup_j a_{k_j}$, but these tuples may not have any relation to one another in general.

When $m = d$, it simplifies because they must be the same $m$-tuple of indices. Namely we know that $$ \bigcap_{j \in J} K_j = \{(a_1,\ldots,a_m) \in S_r^m : \exists \ell \in J , \ell \notin \cup_i a_i \}$$ The cardinality of this is simply $\binom{n-j}{r}^m$, the result of independently choosing a subset of size $r$ from $A - J$ a total of $m$ times. One concludes that

\begin{align}
\tau(n,r,m,m) = | S_r^m| - |V^n_{r,m,d}| &=  \binom{n}{r}^m -\sum_{j = 1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1} \binom{n}{j} \binom{n-j}{r}^m \\
&=\sum_{j = 0}^{n} (-1)^{j} \binom{n}{j} \binom{n-j}{r}^m \end{align} *Note that the upper bound for the sum in the answer to the other problem is (with respect to the variables here) $n - r$ and not $n$ as it is here. If mine is the one which is mistaken please leave a comment.*